# How to implement ADAL library in iOS to authenticate the user on AD B2C

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to integrate ADAL library in iOS native app to authenticate the user on AD B2C by passing the username and password. I'm able to authenticate the user on AD using ADAL4J library in Android app.

**Sample code:**

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext  context = new AuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/'+tenant, false, service);
               Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                       resource, clientId, username, password,
                       null);
               result = future.get();
```

How can I achieve the same in iOS? Can you please assist me on this?

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

At present, the Azure B2C doesn't support the **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow**.

However, the Microsoft development team is working on this feature and it may update on this by summer 2017(refer [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential)).

And the Adal4J library also works for the Azure B2C tenant when we use the Authorization code grant flow to interact with Azure B2C Active directory.

Comment: Hey Fei, great answer :) For completeness sake, can you also mention that Adal4J is still a valid option, but only when used with the regular Auth-code flow.

Comment: @Saca of cause:)

Comment: @FeiXue I'm facing issue with policy configuration. In the regular auth-code flow when I have given policy name in the token and authorization endpoints it didn't work. Please help. https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<Tenant_ID>/<Policy_Name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize